# Layer not found in PostGIS db when it is listed by OgrInfo

Tags: postgis, r, rgdal

Getting an error when trying to import a layer into R using the package RGDAL with the following:

```
geofile <- readOGR("PG:dbname=mydb", layer='temp_GIS_dw_file')
```

This returns the following error:

```
Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, 
use_iconv = use_iconv,  : 
Layer not found`
```

Listing the layers with ogrListLayers shows the layer is present:

```
ogrListLayers("PG:dbname=mydb")

[1] "mb2013_clipped"    "mb_merged_testing" "temp_gis_dw_file"  attr(,"driver")
[1] "PostgreSQL"
attr(,"nlayers") 
[1] 3
```

Furthermore, the following successfully imports the layer from the same DB:

```
geofile <- readOGR("PG:dbname=mydb", layer='mb2013_clipped')
```

I have cleaned up the geometry with `ST_MakeValid()` but this did not solve the problem.

What have I done wrong too late at night?

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
```

Comment: try temp_gis_dw_file instead of temp_GIS_dw_file

Comment: Yikes. I thought I copied and pasted it previously but I must not have. And it was too tired. My pride suggests to take this down, but I'll leave it up, in case anyone else is working too late for their own sanity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your casing doesn't match the layer name you listed. 
PostgreSQL is case sensitvie.  Try:

```
geofile <- readOGR("PG:dbname=mydb", layer='temp_gis_dw_file')
```